# Scaling issue with CSS animation

Tags: css, 3d, gsap

I have created a prototype for a carousel which should function similar to the popular "cover flow" interaction, but instead of a photo slide show, it will be used with html in the divs to describe steps in a process. I'm using the Greensock TweenMax library.

It's all working great except for the scaling issue. As each step comes to the front it should scale to be the largest, but it's not working right.  Obviously I'm applying something wrong somewhere.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MaureenDunlap/SjJLQ/

Also there may be an easier way to "template-ize" this to add more steps in the future. Currently I've assigned CSS positions for the cards, but maybe that isn't necessary.

Suggestions welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Carousel Steps</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-js.css"></link>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="Stage">
    <div id="Stage_navigation">
        <div id="Stage_btn1" class="Stage_btn" >
            <div class="button_holder" >
                <div class="nav_button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_button_label">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Stage_btn2" class="Stage_btn">
            <div class="button_holder">
                <div class="nav_button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_button_label">
                2
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="Stage_btn3" class="Stage_btn">
            <div class="button_holder">
                <div class="nav_button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_button_label">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="Stage_btn4" class="Stage_btn">
            <div class="button_holder">
                <div class="nav_button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_button_label">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="Stage_btn5" class="Stage_btn">
            <div class="button_holder">
                <div class="nav_button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_button_label">
                5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Stage_steps" class="Stage_steps">
        <div id="Stage_step_four" class="pos3b">
            <div class="step_container">
                <div class="rectangle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item_text">
                Step 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Stage_step_three" class="pos3a">
        <div class="step_container">
                <div class="rectangle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item_text">
                Step 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Stage_step_five" class="pos2b">
            <div class="step_container">
                <div class="rectangle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item_text">
                Step 5
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Stage_step_two" class="pos2a">
            <div class="step_container">
                <div class="rectangle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item_text">
                Step 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Stage_step_one" class="pos1" >
            <div class="step_container">
                <div class="rectangle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item_text">
                Step 1
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    var b1 = document.getElementById("Stage_btn1");
    var b2 = document.getElementById("Stage_btn2");
    var b3 = document.getElementById("Stage_btn3");
    var b4 = document.getElementById("Stage_btn4");
    var b5 = document.getElementById("Stage_btn5");
    var s1 = document.getElementById("Stage_step_one");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("Stage_step_two");
    var s3 = document.getElementById("Stage_step_three");
    var s4 = document.getElementById("Stage_step_four");
    var s5 = document.getElementById("Stage_step_five");

$(b1).click(function(){
    TweenLite.to(s1, 2, {zIndex:500, position:"absolute", scaleX:1, scaleY:1, left:"0px", top:"0px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s2, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"-132px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s3, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"-210px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s4, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"320px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s5, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"200px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
   });
$(b2).click(function(){
    TweenLite.to(s2, 2, {zIndex:500, position:"absolute", scaleX:1, scaleY:1, left:"0px", top:"0px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s3, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"-132px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s4, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"-210px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s5, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"320px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s1, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"200px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    });
$(b3).click(function(){
    TweenLite.to(s3, 2, {zIndex:500, position:"absolute", scaleX:1, scaleY:1, left:"0px", top:"0px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s4, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"-132px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s5, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"-210px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s1, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"320px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s2, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"200px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    });
$(b4).click(function(){
    TweenLite.to(s4, 2, {zIndex:500, position:"absolute", scaleX:1, scaleY:1, left:"0px", top:"0px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s5, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"-132px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s1, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"-210px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s2, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"320px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s3, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"200px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    });
$(b5).click(function(){
    TweenLite.to(s5, 2, {zIndex:500, position:"absolute", scale:(1,1), left:"0px", top:"0px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s1, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"-132px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s2, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"-210px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s3, 2, {zIndex:100, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.72651, scaleY:0.72651, left:"320px", top:"51px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(s4, 2, {zIndex:300, position:"absolute", scaleX:0.82581, scaleY:0.82581, left:"200px", top:"31px", ease:Power4.easeOut});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body, html{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#Stage{
    position: relative; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    width: 950px; 
    height: 500px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*  NAVIGATION BUTTONS  */

#Stage_navigation{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 338px; 
    top: 456px; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 32px; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.Stage_btn{
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    margin-left:20px;
    width: 34px; 
    height: 32px; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display:inline-block;
}
.nav_button{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 34px; 
    height: 32px; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    border-top-left-radius: 50%; 
    border-top-right-radius: 50%; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192); 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.nav_button_label{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 12px; 
    top: 7px; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
    font-size: 20px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    font-weight: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-style: normal; 
    text-align: center
}

/*  CONTENT PANELS  */

.Stage_steps{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 279px; 
    top: 28px; 
    width: 402px; 
    height: 415px; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.step_container{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 402px; 
    height: 415px; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 

    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-55px, -56px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.72651, 0.72651); 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.rectangle{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 496px; 
    height: 415px; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    text-align: center;


    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-47px, 0px) translateZ(0px) rotate(0deg)
}
.item_text{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 99px; 
    top: 54px; 
    width: 80px; 
    height: auto; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    font-weight: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-style: normal; 
    text-align: center;
}
.pos1{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 402px; 
    height: 415px; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    scale:(1,1);

}
.pos2a{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: -132px; 
    top: 31px; 
    width: 332px; 
    height: 343px; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scale:(0.82581,0.82581);

}
.pos2b{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 200px; 
    top: 31px; 
    width: 332px; 
    height: 343px; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scale:(0.82581,0.82581);

}
.pos3a{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: -210px; 
    top: 51px; 
    width: 292px; 
    height: 302px; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scale:(0.72651, 0.72651);
}
.pos3b{
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0px; 
    left: 320px; 
    top: 51px; 
    width: 292px; 
    height: 302px; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scale:(0.72651, 0.72651);

}
```

Comment: what you exactly want ?

Comment: You have not included the TweenMax library in your Fiddle.

Comment: It is included under external resources in the Fiddle

Comment: @luckyamit, I am trying to figure out why the items are not scaling properly as they come forward and recede.

Comment: As Moob says, the fiddle doesn't work, the TweenMax is not included

Comment: just include TweenMax library to scale properly if it not work then you can get help from this link [help scale](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/02/scaling-web-page-elements-using-the-css3-scale-transform/)

Comment: YOU should include the library in YOUR fiddle and update the link!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your maths. To illustrate:
If you scale an item down to 80% you need to scale it up by 125% to get back to your original size. So when you're scaling to '1' you're effectively saying "*1 x its current size*"

Answer (score 0):

I found a bunch of things wrong. In my CSS I was mis-using the scale property and needed to put it as part of "transform".

Also I needed to take the dimensions out of the pos1, pos2a, etc declarations and let the scaling take care of the sizing.

Anyway, here is the fixed up version.

http://maureendunlap.com/vif/carousel.html

Thanks for the help!